# Javascript set class by date greater than

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, date

i have problem with script that set css class on table td if date is greater than. Script work only on today if. Rest of ifs should set class if date in td is lower than week and greater than week.

```
$('td:nth-child(7) ').each(function() {

        var today = new Date();
        var week = new Date();
        var dd = today.getDate();
        var ddd = today.getDate()+7;
        var mm = today.getMonth()+1;
        var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

        if(dd<10) {
            dd = '0'+dd
        } 

        if(mm<10) {
            mm = '0'+mm
        } 

        today = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + yyyy;

        if ($(this).text() == today) {
            $(this).closest("td").addClass("red");
        }
        if ($(this).text() < today + 7 && $(this).text() != today ) {
            $(this).closest("td").addClass("yellow");
        }
        if ($(this).text() > today + 7) {
            $(this).closest("td").addClass("green");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you add some html code ?

Comment: try using other variable for `today` text (maybe `todayText`), now log `today + 7 ` and see if it's a date or a string that youv'e wanted

Answer (score 0):

try something like

```
    var displayedDate = new Date($(this).text());
    var today = new Date();
    if (displayedDate > today.setDate(today.getDate() + 7) {
      // here displayed date is posterior to today + 7 days

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing strings, not dates. You should instead convert the date in the cell to a [`Date` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

And when comparing equality of the dates you should use `valueOf()` to avoid a reference comparison.

Here's a working example:

```js
$('td').each(function() {

  var today = new Date();
  today.setHours(0,0,0,0);
  
  var nextWeek = new Date(today);
  nextWeek.setDate(nextWeek.getDate() + 7);
  
  var cellDateParts = $(this).text().split("/");
  var cellDate = new Date(cellDateParts[2], parseInt(cellDateParts[1]) - 1, cellDateParts[0]);
  
  if (cellDate.valueOf() === today.valueOf()) {
    $(this).closest("td").addClass("red");
  } else if (cellDate < nextWeek) {
    $(this).closest("td").addClass("yellow");
  } else if (cellDate > nextWeek) {
    $(this).closest("td").addClass("green");
  }
});
```

```css
.red {
  background: red;
}

.yellow {
  background: yellow;
}

.green {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <td>07/07/2017</td>
  <td>07/08/2017</td>
  <td>23/07/2017</td>
</table>
```